# How to find duplicate entries in collection using aggregation

Tags: mongodb

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f127fa55e7242718200002d"), "id":1, "name" : "foo"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f127fa55e7242718200002d"), "id":2, "name" : "bar"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f127fa55e7242718200002d"), "id":3, "name" : "baz"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f127fa55e7242718200002d"), "id":4, "name" : "foo"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f127fa55e7242718200002d"), "id":5, "name" : "bar"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f127fa55e7242718200002d"), "id":6, "name" : "bar"}
```

I want to find all the duplicated entries in this collection by the "name" field using aggregation. E.g. "foo" appears twice and "bar" appears 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage in [aggrgation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: "$name",
    count: { $sum: 1 },
    name: { $first: "$name" }
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can group by name and count. And then filter with a count greater that 1.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$name",
        count: { $sum: 1 }
       }
     },
    {
     $match:{count:{$gt:1}}
     }
   ])
```

**Output:**

```
{ "_id" : "foo", "count":2}
{ "_id" : "bar", "count":3}
```